How to supply two MG996R Servos at the same time
I have a Samsung Power Bank. I contend to use it to supply Arduino Uno R3 & 2 MG996 Servo.
One USB-A port for Uno.
Another USB-A for two MG996. However, I don't know how to configure wires, and circuits to supply 2 servos at the same time (I just use 2 servos to make a Laser Turret, meaning not using too much power). I am happy to receive your suggestion.




Not sure what are you asking, can you supply one servo but not two, or what is the problem when you don't know how to supply two servos? Or do you even mean power supply, or perhaps the servo data lines as well?

It is hard to say in English, so I will draw a map. My problem is what wire, or circuit do I need to use to configure this red line?https://imgur.com/a/KEIE8jj

please add the drawing to the question ... do not use comment

If I was in your shoes my go to method would be just to attach the main 5volt coming off the battery to the 5v in on the servo. Your setup isn’t to far off. If I’m not mistaken you will have to ensure all of your grounds are connected together. Which it looks like they were. Just strip the cable and probe for the 5V wire and attach to the servos Power wire and you should be ready to role.
